# android studio no matching variant of project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

After update Android Studio and create the first project I see:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Demo Sample'.
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
    Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-rc03.
     Required by:
         project : com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.4.0-rc03
         project :  com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:7.4.0-rc03
       No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-rc03 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-rc03 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-rc03 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-rc03 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-rc03 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed:

Step 1, open notifications:

[image]

Step 2, click select the Gradle JDK Location

Step 3 Select Embedded JDK

[image]